# Can not inject a factory in a controller angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angulerJS. i have defined a factory to get data from API but when i try to put the factory in a controller i got error.

That is the factory code.

```
(Function () {

    var CategoriesFactory = function($http) {
        var factory = {};

        factory.getCategorys = function(account_id){
            return $http.get('http://localhost:18678/api/Transaction?account_id=2');
        };

        factory.getTransaction = function(acc_id){
            return $http.get('http://localhost:18678/api/Transaction?acc_id=2');
        };

        factory.getTransactionInCategory = function(category_id, from_date, to_date){
            return.$http.get('http://localhost:18678/api/transaction?category='+category_id+'&account=2&from=2015-01-                              01&to=2015-12-30');
        };
        return factory;
    };

    angular.module('AccApp').factory('CategoriesFactory', CategoriesFactory);
 }());
```

here is the controller.

```
app.controller('CategoriesController',
  function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, CategoriesFactory) {

  })
```

and here is the error.
Unknown provider: CategoriesFactoryProvider <- CategoriesFactory

Comment: Is your `app` module called _AccApp_?

Comment: yes it is called AccApp

Comment: @user2918388: Please show all relevant code: How do you initialize your modules, what is the trace for the error you get etc

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must have forgot to inject AccApp into your mai module where you have defined your app.

```
angular.module("app", ['AccApp']);
```

Please do something like this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: var app = angular.module("AccApp",[]); that what i wrote

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to write angular code in a wierd way ?
The goal of angular is the simplicity

```
 var app = angular.module('AccApp',[]);

    app.factory('CategoriesFactory',function($http){// you can cut and paste this factory into a seperate file if you wish
       return{
              getCategorys:function(account_id){
               return $http.get('http://localhost:18678/api/Transaction?account_id=2');
                },
              getTransaction:function(acc_id){
               return $http.get('http://localhost:18678/api/Transaction?acc_id=2');
                },
                getTransactionInCategory : function(category_id, from_date, to_date){
             return.$http.get('http://localhost:18678/api/transaction?category='+category_id+'&account=2&from=2015-01-                              01&to=2015-12-30');
                };
              }
      });
```

Now you can Inject this factory into your controller simply:

```
     app.controller('CategoriesController',function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, CategoriesFactory){

       console.log(CategoriesFactory.getCategorys(getCategorys));
       });
```

Comment: i am trying to separate factory code in a diffrant file

Comment: OK, but do it my way , its the best
now u can cut and paste this factory into a seperate file
I edited

Comment: And why didn't you accept my answer anyway ? wasn't helful ? having stil problem ?